# SharePoint Workflow stuck after task approval

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, tasks, workflow-manager

I have a simple Workflow where I assign a task and write to history some text after the task is approved. The problem is when I approve the task, the workflow gets stuck and refuse to run further even though the task is already changed to "Approved".

Workflow Health only shows this error message

> Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled after 10/16/2016 7:30
>   PM. Details of last request: HTTP InternalServerError to
>   http://win-osqi95jkrf8:8484/DVC2/_api/sp.utilities.utility.SendEmail
>   Correlation Id: 9749cf9f-e74a-1c08-a1a5-702b8549f4cc Instance Id:
>   c3841289-b0f4-4288-bea0-229c3f1e5883 Exception of type
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' was thrown.

From my understanding, this error only prevents the workflow from sending notification emails, not makes it halt altogether.

Any help would be appreciated.

My Workflow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZjqH.jpg. It's a simple workflow for testing purpose where I assign task and then write to history once the task is completed. However when I approve the task there's nothing written to the history list and the workflow stuck at "Started" stage forever.

Comment: Could you post screenshots of the workflow or give us the steps immediately before and after the area in question?

Comment: I edited to add my screenshot

Comment: can you goto your error logs on the server and look for the error id 9749cf9f-e74a-1c08-a1a5-702b8549f4cc it will tell you exactly why its failing. post an update here an I could help

Comment: I looked in the logs using ULS Viewer, there's no Unexpected error. Everything is high or medium.

Comment: can you show a screen dump of your workflow how your setup the email part of the workflow? added answer that could be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

you need to post your actual error from the servers error log in 15hive:

look for error  `9749cf9f-e74a-1c08-a1a5-702b8549f4cc`  and post an update.

based on little information and the error looks like your mail service is not setup properly or not setup atall.

`ConfigurationErrorsException` and `sp.utilities.utility.SendEmail` is a big hint that smtp might not be correctly setup, check on central admin for outgoing smtp is configured located under "system settings" -> "e-mail and text messages" -> "Configure outgoing e-mail settings". Without looking at the actual error I would not know but usually people setup smtp on sharepoint but forget to configure exchange to allow sending out messages from the sharepoint server. You would need to add the sharepoint server ip address to exchange server allowed machines list so that sharepoint has the correct permission to send emails.

for exchange 2013 relay settings:

http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000891

other issue could be that the AD account your using doesn't have an email address. make sure it does and also check on central admin user profile properties for that user that they have an email address.

Comment: The SMTP server is not setup since this is a test machine. I used to work with workflow before, and if I did not setup the SMTP server then it would cause the notification emails to not sent, but the workflow still continues nevertheless.

Comment: can you show what you have in your single task configuration?